# Multiple QueryParams with same key

Tags: angular

I'm working on a filter and my filter has categories:

- Colour
- Size
- Origin

Now I'm having a bit trouble to deal with multiple filter. Something like:

```
www.myApp.com/search?query=*&colour=blue&size=medium,large&origin=germany
```

First of all I'm wondering if about the syntax of the URL and if there is a standard? This is especially about the `size`, for example. In the show URL, I show the values like this: `size=medium,large`. But sometimes I see urls showing: `size=medium&size=large`.

Is there a right way?

And further more how can I deal with multiple same keys in angular2/4? It seem that the `this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {});` is not able to detect changes in an existing QueryParams. So for example coming from:

```
www.myApp.com/search?query=*&colour=blue&origin=germany
```

Adding size=medium woks:

```
www.myApp.com/search?query=*&colour=blue&size=medium&origin=germany
```

But the change detection is not piking up if I add another element, like:

```
www.myApp.com/search?query=*&colour=blue&size=medium,large&origin=germany
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma is a reserved character in a URL query. According to the standards, but that doesn't mean you can't use it. You just need to escape the character first.

So you would write the URL like this:

```
www.myApp.com/search?query=*&colour=blue&size=medium%2Clarge&origin=germany
```

That can be a pain in some cases. So you can use the plus character `+` instead of comma since it's not a reserved character.

```
www.myApp.com/search?query=*&colour=blue&size=medium+large&origin=germany
```

I see a lot of websites use the plus.

The reason Angular might not be picking up the change detection on the URL is because the comma wasn't escaped (but this is just an assumption I'm making).

As for the the question of passing multiple parameters. Well, there is no wrong way. When it comes to the structure of the query parameters there are no enforced rules about this.

You can do any pattern of URL you want:

```
www.myApp.com/search?query=*&colour=blue&size=medium+large&origin=germany
www.myApp.com/search?query=*&colour=blue&size=medium&size=large&origin=germany
www.myApp.com/search?query=*&colour=blue&size[]=medium&size[]=large&origin=germany
www.myApp.com/search?query=*&colour=blue&size[0]=medium&size[1]=large&origin=germany
```

My personal preference is to do what's easier. If you are working with a back-end server. I would follow what ever pattern that server requires even on the front-end. This makes the pattern consistent, but if the back-end isn't an issue. I would just use `+` and split the parameter when you need it.